# How to replace & in a excel cell using macros vb

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

Below is a part of my macro function. The cell value of (r,47) could have & entered by the user. I would like to replace the "&" entered with "&" followed by "amp;". (Note: The convoluted method "&" followed by "amp;" is used as amp; is dropped in this editor.")

I tried substitute, but it gives syntax error when I try to save the macro.

Currently I have this statement in my macro function.

```
Print #fnum, "<College><School>" & Cells(r, 47) & "</School></College>"
```

and I tried the below one.

```
Print #fnum, "<College><School>" & Cells(r, 47).Substitute('&','&amp;') & "</School></College>"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should use double quote when defining strings.
2. Substitute wont work.  It's a worksheet function, not a method of a range object.
3. Try VBA Replace function instead

   `Print #fnum, "<College><School>" & Replace(Cells(r, 47), "&", "&amp") & "</School></College>"`

Comment: It just missed an ; after "&amp" Print #fnum, "<College><School>" & Replace(Cells(r, 47), "&", "&amp;") & "</School></College>"